# Making a plug and play setup for devices connecting to the Pi

Tags: gpio, electronics, c++, communication

Hopefully I am asking in the right place, being electrical and code, not sure. In short, I want to create a plug and play setup for different devices(mostly sensors and relays) to be attached.

Originally I paid someone to do this, and it technically works, but he wrote a custom protocol to do it. After talking with some other people, they mentioned a standard protocol I can maybe use, but forgot the name.

What I need to accomplish:

- 300ft communication via custom wired RJ45 cable (using for power ect, not tcp)
- When a device is plugged in, it should tell the system it's typeId and uniqueId

  - Devices will have a typeId such as 1234 for all temperature sensors
  - Devices will have a uniqueId so the Pi can differentiate between multiple of the same sensors.
- Virtually unlimited connected devices (so something like a 2wire setup won't work)
- Should only use a few gpio ports for all connections, not 1 for each device.

Mostly looking for a more standard protocol I can use vs a custom one if possible. All the code is C++ and some pic16 code right now. Still learning all this, so any direction would be helpful.

Thanx ahead of time.

Comment: I would have thought we would all be using such a protocol if it existed.  Given that we are not it is probably non-existent or terribly expensive.  Possibly why your developer went for a custom solution.

Comment: For anyone else looking, I wanted to give an update, but no answer yet. From the information I have gathered, doing rs485 with modbus looks like it will work. There doesn't seem to be an issue with needing repeaters, tho I can't find when those are actually needed. As for P&P without defining the ID's ahead of time, the ID's can be changed on the fly. So it can have a Default id and then immediately change it to something not already used. Still working on getting it all working, but not my primary project.

Answer (score 1):

For Plug and Play you should check UPnP protocol (simply: Universal Plug'n'Play). Google it and check http://www.upnp-hacks.org/upnp.html

For wired connections of sensors and relays you can also try reading about KNX open standard - also try google.

Good luck!

Comment: Looking up [KNX](http://www.knx.org/knx-en/index.php) initially looked promising, though I saw that it is open in so far as everyone using it must use the same standards and not so much anyone could use it themselves - any place it is used must be installed by trained/licensed(?) installers.  It seems there is standard software to design such things - but it is Windows only and licensed, which to my mind suggests that using KNX with Pis is not so likely.

On the other hand [OpenHAB](http://www.openhab.org/) looks more promising (though it does seem to know about KNX)...

Comment: Agreed SlySven. KNX doesn't look like it will work. Will take a look at OpenHAB. The KNX search also turned up Modbus which is what someone mentioned and looks promising also. Bunch to research tho.

Comment: OpenHAB is a wonderful piece of software (I use it myself) so I highly recommend it. On the other hand if you want to try some alternatives to it - check AGO (http://www.agocontrol.com/) or domoticz (https://domoticz.com/)